# Pointer problems with overloading in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, overloading

Pointers present some special problems for overload resolution.

Say for example,

```
void f(int* x) { ... }
void f(char* x) { ...}
int main()
{
    f(0);
}
```

What is wrong with calling f(0)?  How can I fix the function call for f(0)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`f((int*) 0)` or `f((char *) 0)`

But if you find yourself doing this I would take another look at your design.

Comment: Is it because chars are represented as numbers or?

Comment: It is because you can't infer the type from just a zero

Comment: 0 means null pointer in C++.  So it could be a null int* or a null char*.  Compiler can't determine which one.

Comment: Technically, it's a "null pointer constant", not a "null pointer". All pointers, including null pointers are have pointer type. Null pointer constants are integral constants.

Answer (score 0):

Cast it, or don't use it at all:

```
f((int*)0);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with calling f(0) is the resolution is ambiguous. Both of your overloaded functions take a pointer which in this case can only be resolved via cast.

```
f((int*)0)
```

Depending on what you're trying to do here there are other options that are not ambiguous.